# print out two dimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to print out two dimensional arrays from the results of an sql statement in php

so far i have this code

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($searchResults); $i++) {
print "<tr>";
print "<td>";
print "$searchResults[$i]['username']";
print "</td>";
print "<td>";
print "<a href=\"viewprofile.php?email=$searchResults[$i]['email'] 
     \">$searchResults[$i]['email']</a>";
print "</td>";
print "</tr>";
  }
```

but instead of printing out the value in the array it prints out things like $array['username'] instead and i dont want to use for each loops since the second condition has to be a link any ideas?

Comment: Use a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do multidimensional arrays in a string the way you are doing it:

```
print "$searchResults[$i]['username']";
print "<a href=\"viewprofile.php?email=$searchResults[$i]['email'] 
 \">$searchResults[$i]['email']</a>";
```

Change them to this:

```
print $searchResults[$i]['username'];
print "<a href=\"viewprofile.php?email=".$searchResults[$i]['email']." 
 \">".$searchResults[$i]['email']."</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

It's having problems parsing array syntax. Just take out the double quotes

```
print $searchResults[$i]['username'];
print "<a href=\"viewprofile.php?email=" . $searchResults[$i]['email'] .
     "\">" . $searchResults[$i]['email'] . "</a>";
```

If you insist on having PHP parse, read more on string parsing http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

For array syntax, you don't need the quotes, eg

```
print "{$searchResults[$i][username]}";
```

(notice no quotes around 'username'). Don't work with variables though, unless you use those curly braces (again just read up). Better to just use concat

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($searchResults as $result) {
    print "<tr>";
    print "<td>";
    print $result['username'];
    print "</td>";
    print "<td>";
    print "<a href=\"viewprofile.php?email=$result[email] 
         \">$result[email]</a>";
    print "</td>";
   print "</tr>";
}
```

Note that when embedding an array variable inside a `" "` string, you dont single quote escape the array keys. (`$result[email]` instead of `$result['email']`).